# Source for feints, fakes and setups

Tags: boxing, muay-thai, kickboxing

I would like to and actually I need to add proper setups to launch and land attacks. Do you know any source, be it a dvd, a youtube clip/channel, a text file or whatever where one could look up some opening techniques, fakes, setups and the like?
I'm also happy about "general" approaches to set up attacks.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the closing. Which multiple problems do I target?

Comment: I'm mixed on this one. In general, questions asking for recommendations don't tend to work well with the site's concept of getting "one right answer" rather than multiple perspectives. The questions is also raised of what is "good and useful" in this case since there's a wide variety of feints, fakes, and setups. And then you get into the difference between something instructional and the "amateur fight" footage which generally doesn't have analysis and instruction. I have not voted, but I'm stating my reasoning for how I might vote.

Comment: Well, ok, I can also change my wording from "what do you recommend for a good source" to "What is a source.." if this changes everything?

Comment: It may also be good to clarify exactly what you're looking for (particularly dodges? Punch techniques? Methods against a particular defense or offense?) and to focus on either instructional videos, or good amateur fights to see the particularly technique you're looking for.

Comment: I'm historically bad at analogies, but right now, your current question kind of comes off like posting to a Football SE asking about "ways to set up running plays, or good games to watch" with tags for American Football, Rugby, and Australian Football. It's very broad, and asking for more than one thing.

Comment: ok, will clarify but I don't see the broad tags, they are all about striking. Sure, dodge & weave is not that common in thai boxing but I would also be happy to get input here. However, I will change soon.

Comment: The problem with this question is that any source is equally useful. Why would any answer be better than another answer? If you are just looking to start conversation, the chat room is always open.

Comment: Yeah, true,..  but how shall I ask to get some inputs?

Comment: [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79444/open-roda) is always open